# Extract unique email addresses from excel column

Tags: excel, formula, worksheet-function

I have a list of 250k email addresses. The email addresses are in column A of the worksheet. I am trying to extract every email address that is not a duplicate on this list into it's own column (C). Since 70-75% of these email addresses are duplicates it should leave me with about 40k unique email addresses.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Select the column then `Data>>Advanced Filter>>Copy to another location+Unique records only`

Answer (score 5):

Use `Data > Remove Duplicates` feature, copy entire column to C beforehand.